# Como instalar pacotes .NET Core do Nuget usando o VS Code?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget

Eu estou usando o VS Code para desenvolver um projeto em .NET Core e gostaria de saber como faço para instalar pacotes no Nuget nele.

No Visual Studio, existe um terminal específico pra isto, o **Package Manager Console**. Nele é preciso usar o comando `Add-Package` para instalar algo.

Por exemplo, para instalar o Entity Framework pode-se usar este comando

```
PM> Add-Package EntityFramework
```

Como posso instalar um pacote usando o Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Usando o comando `dotnet add` do CLI do .NET Core

É possível fazer isto usando o CLI do .NET Core com o comando **`dotnet add`**, a opção `package` e o nome do pacote logo em seguida.

Por exemplo, para adicionar a última versão do Entity Framework.

```bsh
$ dotnet add package EntityFramework
```

Para especificar uma versão, é possível usar o argumento `--version`.

```bsh
$ dotnet add package EntityFramework --version=6.0
```

Para especificar o projeto em que a dependência deve ser adicionada é preciso usar o caminho do arquivo **csproj** do projeto logo após o `add`.

Por exemplo, para adicionar o Entity Framework no projeto **`ProjetoModels`**

```bsh
$ dotnet add ProjetoModels.csproj package EntityFramework
```

Isso vai verificar se a versão do pacote é compatível com o projeto e, caso seja compatível, irá adicionar a dependência nos arquivos do projeto e também baixá-lo usando o comando **`dotnet restore`**.

> **Dica**: para abrir um terminal dentro do VS Code, na pasta do projeto use a combinação de teclas <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**'**</kbd>

#### Adicionar a dependência manualmente no XML

Também é possível adicionar a referência manualmente no arquivo do projeto. Para isso é só abrir o arquivo o **.csproj**, procurar pela seção **`ItemGroup`** e adicionar um item **`PackageReference`**.

Por exemplo, para adicionar o Entity Framework versão **6.2.0**.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Depois disso, é preciso rodar o comando **`dotnet restore`** para que os arquivos sejam baixados.

- [Documentação **`dotnet add`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package)
- [Documentação do **`dotnet restore`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore?tabs=netcore2x)

Answer (score 3):

Outra opção seria utilzar a extensão

> jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager

que permite adicionar pacotes de forma gráfica, após instalar a extensão e reiniciar o vscode, é necessário:

1. Abrir o "Command Palete" normalmente utilizando Ctrl + shift + p, procurar por "Nuget Package Manager" e digitar o nome do pacote que deseja instalar, isso é util quando não se sabe exatamenente o nome do pacote, pois será exibido uma lista com todos os resultados que atenderem a busca.
2. Clicar no pacote desejado
3. Escolher a versão
4. Escolher em qual projeto será instalado
5. Será exibido uma opção sugerindo executar o restore no projeto no qual o pacote foi adicionado, ou realizar o **dotnet restore** manualmente

É muito útil quando não se tem certeza no nome completo do pacote, ou para pessoas que preferem trabalhar de forma gráfica.

Comment: Gostei da opção, não conhecia isso.